# Front load washer - white stuff around drum bearing

Tags: washing-machine

[image]I have an approximately 10 year old Whirlpool front load washer. Today, after washing a load that possibly had some grit in it, there is some white stuff around where the drum spins. Also, when turning the drum, it sounds like something is grinding. Could grit have destroyed the front drum bearing? Any recommendations on what to do next?

[image]

Comment: Been watching videos since I posted this. I think the white stuff is from some paver dust and not some seal that has come apart. I think I need to take the front off and clean it out.

Comment: So, take the white stuff, and "wash it." Does it smear like grease? Does it feel like sandpaper? Wash easily or need a grease cutting detergent?

Comment: The white stuff is actually plastic that has rubbed off outer tub.The drum wobbles and somehow bent enough to wear off part of the tub. I decided to bag the machine since not only is the drum or shaft warped, but the outer lip of the tub is worn off in places.